# Connect OracleDB in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle-sqldeveloper, pypyodbc

I need to connect Oracle DB and run scripts in Python but not sure how to do it. I currently use Oracle SQL Developer to run my queries. Please help, Attached screen shot has connection details from  Oracle SQL Developer.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the oracle web site there is a good tutorial that helped me a lot: [Tutorial: Using Python with Oracle Database 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html).

I had to import the [cx_Oracle library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1) and I write the follow code:

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@IP:Port/DatabaseName')
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('my query')
for result in cur:
    print(result)
cur.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: The old tutorial reference has been obsoleted.  The current tutorial for the (now renamed cx_Oracle) driver is at https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-The-New-Wave-of-Scripting.html